# GRUB does not show Arch Linux during startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I recently installed Arch Linux on my Windows partition via USB boot.

But GRUB still shows Windows during startup on the partition. I already tried reconfiguring the `grub.cfg`:

```
$ sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg    
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-57-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Arch on /dev/sda4
Found Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (14.04) on /dev/sda9
done
```

It says it would find Arch, but during the startup there is still Windows displayed.

This is how my partitions look currently:

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sda print                                    
Model: ATA SAMSUNG MZ7TE256 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  1050MB  1049MB  ntfs                                          hidden, diag
 2      1050MB  1322MB  273MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot, esp
 3      1322MB  1456MB  134MB                   Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      1456MB  104GB   103GB   ext4            Basic data partition         
 9      104GB   125GB   21,0GB  ext4            Ubuntu14
 5      125GB   157GB   31,5GB  ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 6      157GB   160GB   3000MB  linux-swap(v1)
 8      160GB   256GB   96,4GB  ext4
 7      256GB   256GB   128MB                                                 bios_grub
```

On partition 8 is Ubuntu 16, which I mainly use, and on which the GRUB files are, too.

Comment: Are you looking at the UEFI menu. With UEFI you have at least two boot managers (menus). UEFI has a menu of systems that have installed boot code into the ESP - efi system partition. And grub has a menu of systems it has found that it can offer to boot. If you want to remove old entries from UEFI menu, you can use efibootmgr. See `man efibootmgr` & but choose whichever entries you want to remove: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Comment: I don't boot via UEFI, but legacy BIOS

Comment: Then you must still have the Windows boot partition with bootmgr & BCD. Grub2's os-prober looks for those files on any partition to know if that partition is bootable. You show an UEFI system with the ESP - efi system partition and no bios_grub that is requried for BIOS boot on gpt. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible, so all systems need to be in same boot mode for grub to find them. If multiple grubs and BIOS then only one grub is in control. 
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info